# How do I compare changes between branches in Paw Cloud?

Tags: paw-app

When working with git, I'm in the habit of reviewing all of my changes before pushing. I'd like to be able to do the same for Paw. I just can't seem to find any information on making this or other comparisons. I'd also like to see what others have pushed to their branches before merging into master.